# How to upgrade all outdated packages easily for magento2

Tags: composer-php, magento2

I am on the latest version of magento2 CE (currently 2.3.3), I use composer for upgrades
`composer outdated`
shows me a lot of outdated packages.
How to easily upgrade/update these outdated packages to the latest versions?

Tried require them one by one, which is a lot of hassle, also because inter dependencies

another sub question is, does composer look at which packages are compatible with magento 2.3.3 when it tells which packages are outdated? perhaps i can better stay with the packages as bundled with the default magento 2.3.3 project composer.conf as they might be mostly tested with and compatible.

Comment: `composer update`?